# Comparing cointainers of pointers in googlemock

Tags: c++, stl, containers, googletest, googlemock

I need to test a class (let's say it's called `Caller`) with this method:

```
void Caller::callMe(map<string, string> argument);
```

That class holds a pointer to another class (let's say `Executor`), which has this method:

```
void Executor::addVector(vector< shared_ptr<AbstractClass> > aVector);
```

I want to test that, when `Caller::callMe()` is invoked, it uses the `map<string>` argument to create a `ConcreteClass` object (an implementation of the `AbstractClass` interface), creates a `vector< shared_ptr<ConcreteClass> >` object and passes is to `Executor::addVector()`.

For this purpose I create a `MockExecutor` such as:

```
MOCK_METHOD1( addVector, void(vector<shared_ptr<AbstractClass> >) );
```

and pass it to my `Caller` instance.

The `Caller::callMe()` method derives the `vector< shared_ptr<ConcreteClass> >` from the map that I'm passing, i.e. the values of the vector are not known in advance before invoking `Caller::callMe()`.

This means that, in order to test if the `ConcreteClass` items in the vector match the expected values, I can't just do:

```
vector< shared_ptr<ConcreteClass> > expectedVector;
for(size_t i = 0; i < expectedLength; ++i)
{ /* initialise vector with expected values */ }

EXPECT_CALL( *mockExecutor, addVector(expectedVector) );
```

or

```
EXPECT_CALL( *mockExecutor, addVector(ElementsAre(..., ...) );
```

because the `shared_ptr` items will be different and I actually need to compare the values **pointed to** by the shared_ptr items, also handling the cast from `AbstractClass` to `ConcreteClass`.

I've read that it's possible to compare the pointed to values in googlemock using `Pointee()` [1], and that it's possible to do type casting with `SafeMatcherCast()` [2] but I'm having troubles of making the whole thing to work.

How can I write such a test in googlemock? Or, is it possible to achieve that using a custom matcher?

Thank you!

[1] https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Validating_the_Value_Pointed_to_by_a_Pointer_Argument

[2] https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/V1_7_CookBook#Casting_Matchers

Comment: See, if this post helps to solve your problem:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616475/can-google-mock-a-method-with-a-smart-pointer-return-type/11548191#11548191

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't seem to solve my problem, or at least I can't see how to apply it to my situation. Actually I realised that I needed to be more specific, so I edited my question adding more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are likely a few different ways to do this, but the first thing that comes to my mind is using a custom matcher. Assuming that ConcreteClass above looks like this:

```
class ConcreteClass : public AbstractClass {
public:
    unsigned value;
};
```

You could write a custom matcher which takes care of the downcasting for you:

```
MATCHER_P(DownCastClassHasValue, value, "") {
    return reinterpret_cast<const ConcreteClass*>(&arg)->value == value;
}
```

This would be used thusly:

```
EXPECT_CALL( *mockExecutor, addVector(AllOf(
        Contains(Pointee(DownCastClassHasValue(1))),
        Contains(Pointee(DownCastClassHasValue(2))))));
```

&c. The expectation is not exactly pretty, but I think it'll do what you want.

Comment: Thank you, that did the job :)