# How can I mock a method with a return type of unique_ptr in Google Mock?

Tags: c++, mocking, unique-ptr, googlemock

I have read [Can Google Mock a method with a smart pointer return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616475/can-google-mock-a-method-with-a-smart-pointer-return-type) but it did not really give much of an answer.

I have a factory that returns unique_ptr instances. Returning unique_ptr is a requirement that cannot change without really good reason and a discussion with those above my pay grade (which I am willing to do if it plain turns out you should not be returning these things).

In the code being tested, there are three objects in question. The first is a handler of sorts. Using that handler, you can create the second object, which is the only real interesting one after everything is said and done. But creating that second one is a complex process that requires extra work done by the specific handler instance, as well as a factory (the third object) to take care of logic needed in creating Mr. Second regardless of handler requirements.

Here's the testing code in question (with class names changed in order to avoid HR hell):

```
class BarTest : public ::testing::Test
{
protected:
    Bar foo;
};

TEST_F(BarTest, createFoo)
{
    // Data used in this test
    std::string fooName = "test";
    MockFooFactory<int> fooFactory;

    MockFoo<int>* foo = new MockFoo<int>;

    // When createFoo is called, it should call the foo factory's construct method with the given
    // fooName and a pointer to the calling bar
    EXPECT_CALL(fooFactory, construct(fooName, &bar)).
        WillOnce(::testing::Return(std::unique_ptr<Foo<int>>(foo)));

    // Test it
    std::unique_ptr<Foo<int>> returnedFoo = bar.createFoo(fooName, fooFactory);

    // createFoo should return the foo returned by the factory's construct method
    ASSERT_EQ(foo, returnedFoo.get());
}
```

As one might expect, upon compiling this (specifically with GCC) the compiler complains about using the deleted copy constructor. I do not think there is a way to finagle this around in order to impose move semantics (at the very least not through the admittedly naive approaches I tried), and just telling it to return the raw pointer and hoping it can wrap it up itself also failed (potentially naive as well), so I am stuck.

At this point I am really leaning towards making a fake, but I would like to give it one last shot with pure mocking. If there is some way I can get this return to work, that would be fantastic. Either way, I have full control over the mocking and testing, so as long as this case gets covered (hopefully without hackiness) how direct or indirect the approach is not a concern.

Comment: If you were already reading that linked post, why didn't my answer solve your problem??

Comment: Personally, I would rather just set up a fake if it got to that point. I have both the factory and the instance being created under my control, so a fake, in my opinion, would be easier to understand and maintain should someone need to. Note that I am not saying your answer is not useful; if someone could not (or for whatever reason absolutely did not want to) use a fake, it is about the only feasible option.

Comment: Well, you may blame the designers of GoogleMock, that they made it so (was merely done in the mentioned discussion thread). At least I use this workaround for unit testing our production code that uses `std::auto_ptr` in many interfaces. I doubt you'll gain any other answer to your question.

Comment: Is this not covered in the cookbook? [Mocking Methods That Use Move-Only Types](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Mocking_Methods_That_Use_Move-Only_Types)

Comment: @RobKennedy I was using the 1.7.0 release, which does not include that. However, grabbing a more recent version of the code gives it to me. I will have to figure out if I am allowed to use a non-release version of gmock, but if you want to make your comment an answer, I will mark it correct since it is indeed the way to do it.

Comment: I must admit I didn't really read the link very closely. I'd there something in there that isn't supported by the 1.7.0 released code? Or is it just that the cookbook *document* included in that release doesn't describe the technique you need to use? If the latter, then I can't imagine any reason you couldn't use it.

Comment: I should be more clear, 1.7.0 does not have the move-only support at all, and as such the documentation for 1.7.0 also doesn't have it. That is why it's a question of whether or not I can use it myself. However, seeing how it is exactly the solution to this problem, I feel like it should be documented as such for everyone that can use the trunk version.

Answer (score 21):

I know this post is very old and you've probably discovered the answer by now.

However, a new piece of information is that in April 2017, gmock introduced a new Action modifier "ByMove".

```
EXPECT_CALL(*foo_, Bar(_, )).WillOnce(Return(ByMove(some_move_only_object)));
```

Comment: The syntax would actually be `ByMove(std::move(some_move_only_object))`. Also note that returning a `nullptr` also requires `ByMove(nullptr)`.