# How to mock a method that returns auto_ptr?

Tags: c++, googlemock

I want to mock a method that is returning a auto_ptr.

So far I did this,

```
class ClassAMock : public ClassA
{
public:

    MOCK_METHOD0(method, std::auto_ptr<MyClass>());
};
```

and I am getting this error,

```
Error   78  error C2558: class 'std::auto_ptr<MyClass>' : no copy constructor available or copy constructor is declared 'explicit'
```

Help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you post the content of the MyClass class?

Comment: [Can Google Mock a method with a smart pointer return type?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7616475/3953764)