# Setting expectations for a GoogleMock causes a memory leak

Tags: c++, mocking, googletest, unique-ptr, googlemock

I am testing a class that takes multiple std::unique_ptr in initialisation. Raw pointers of mock objects are allocated with new, and then passed to an injected unique_ptr.

A test without any expectations passes fine. When I add an expectation, I get memory leaks.

The sources:

Tested class:

```
class TemperatureController : public IController
{
public:
  TemperatureController(std::unique_ptr<IOutput> output,
                        std::unique_ptr<ISensor> sensor,
                        std::unique_ptr<IRegulator> regulator,
                        std::unique_ptr<ISetpoint> setpoint,
                        std::unique_ptr<IEnabler> enabler) :
    output(std::move(output)),
    sensor(std::move(sensor)),
    regulator(std::move(regulator)),
    setpoint(std::move(setpoint)),
    enabler(std::move(enabler))
  { }

  virtual ~TemperatureController(){}

  virtual void setup() override;
  virtual void controlLoop() override;

private:
  std::unique_ptr<IOutput> output;
  std::unique_ptr<ISensor> sensor;
  std::unique_ptr<IRegulator> regulator;
  std::unique_ptr<ISetpoint> setpoint;
  std::unique_ptr<IEnabler> enabler;
};

void TemperatureController::controlLoop()
{
  cout << "enabler address in sut = " << std::hex <<  *((int*)(enabler.get())) << endl;
  cout << "regulator address in sut = 4" << std::hex <<  *((int*)(regulator.get())) << endl;
  if(enabler->isEnabled())
  {
    regulator->controllOutput(*output,
                              *setpoint,
                              *sensor);
  }
}
```

Test suite:

```
template <typename T>
auto injectMock(T* ptr)
{
  return unique_ptr<T>(ptr);
}


struct TestTemperatureController : public Test
{
  MockIEnabler* enabler = new MockIEnabler();
  MockIOutput* output = new MockIOutput();
  MockIRegulator* regulator = new MockIRegulator();
  MockISensor* sensor = new MockISensor();
  MockISetpoint* setpoint = new MockISetpoint();

  TemperatureController sut{injectMock(output),
                            injectMock(sensor),
                            injectMock(regulator),
                            injectMock(setpoint),
                            injectMock(enabler)};

  TestTemperatureController()
  {
    cout << "enabler address in test = "
         << std::hex <<  *((int*)(enabler)) << endl
         << "regulator address in test = "
         << std::hex <<  *((int*)(regulator)) << endl;
  }

};




TEST_F(TestTemperatureController,
       WhenEnabled_ShouldAct)
{
  EXPECT_CALL(*enabler, isEnabled())
      .WillOnce(Return(true));
  //EXPECT_CALL(*regulator, controllOutput(_,_,_)) // commented out to make simpler logs
  //    .Times(AtLeast(1));

  sut.controlLoop();
}
```

I ommited some noise code (includes, namespaces etc.).

When run with valgrind, I get the following output:

```
==10176== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==10176== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==10176== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==10176== Command: ./unit_tests
==10176== 
Running main() from gmock_main.cc
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from TestTemperatureController
[ RUN      ] TestTemperatureController.WhenEnabled_ShouldAct
enabler address in test = 54edc8
regulator address in test = 54eb90
enabler address in sut = 54edc8
regulator address in sut = 454eb90

GMOCK WARNING:
Uninteresting mock function call - returning directly.
    Function call: controllOutput(@0x5cdf1b0 8-byte object <08-ED 54-00 00-00 00-00>, @0x5cdf430 8-byte object <C0-EA 54-00 00-00 00-00>, @0x5cdf390 8-byte object <D8-EA 54-00 00-00 00-00>)
NOTE: You can safely ignore the above warning unless this call should not happen.  Do not suppress it by blindly adding an EXPECT_CALL() if you don't mean to enforce the call.  See https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#knowing-when-to-expect for details.
[       OK ] TestTemperatureController.WhenEnabled_ShouldAct (282 ms)
[----------] 1 test from TestTemperatureController (297 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (369 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.

/home/lukasz/workspace/arduino-thermostat/ut/tests/TestTemperatureController/TestTemperatureController.cpp:52: ERROR: this mock object (used in test TestTemperatureController.WhenEnabled_ShouldAct) should be deleted but never is. Its address is @0x5cdf110.
ERROR: 1 leaked mock object found at program exit.
==10176== 
==10176== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10176==     in use at exit: 74,863 bytes in 37 blocks
==10176==   total heap usage: 231 allocs, 194 frees, 124,341 bytes allocated
==10176== 
==10176== 403 (16 direct, 387 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 35 of 37
==10176==    at 0x4C2E0EF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10176==    by 0x4DE485: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<testing::internal::linked_ptr<testing::internal::ExpectationBase> >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (in /home/lukasz/workspace/build-arduino-thermostat-Desktop-Domyślna/unit_tests)
==10176==    by 0x4DE0F3: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<testing::internal::linked_ptr<testing::internal::ExpectationBase> > >::allocate(std::allocator<testing::internal::linked_ptr<testing::internal::ExpectationBase> >&, unsigned long) (in /home/lukasz/workspace/build-arduino-thermostat-Desktop-Domyślna/unit_tests)
==10176==    by 0x4DDA47: std::_Vector_base<testing::internal::linked_ptr<testing::internal::ExpectationBase>, std::allocator<testing::internal::linked_ptr<testing::internal::ExpectationBase> > >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) (in /home/lukasz/workspace/build-arduino-thermostat-Desktop-Domyślna/unit_tests)
==10176==    by 0x4DD077: void std::vector<testing::internal::linked_ptr<testing::internal::ExpectationBase>, std::allocator<testing::internal::linked_ptr<testing::internal::ExpectationBase> > >::_M_emplace_back_aux<testing::internal::linked_ptr<testing::internal::ExpectationBase> const&>(testing::internal::linked_ptr<testing::internal::ExpectationBase> const&) (in /home/lukasz/workspace/build-arduino-thermostat-Desktop-Domyślna/unit_tests)
==10176==    by 0x4DC562: std::vector<testing::internal::linked_ptr<testing::internal::ExpectationBase>, std::allocator<testing::internal::linked_ptr<testing::internal::ExpectationBase> > >::push_back(testing::internal::linked_ptr<testing::internal::ExpectationBase> const&) (in /home/lukasz/workspace/build-arduino-thermostat-Desktop-Domyślna/unit_tests)
==10176==    by 0x4DB252: testing::internal::FunctionMockerBase<bool ()>::AddNewExpectation(char const*, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::tuple<> const&) (in /home/lukasz/workspace/build-arduino-thermostat-Desktop-Domyślna/unit_tests)
==10176==    by 0x4D9459: testing::internal::MockSpec<bool ()>::InternalExpectedAt(char const*, int, char const*, char const*) (in /home/lukasz/workspace/build-arduino-thermostat-Desktop-Domyślna/unit_tests)
==10176==    by 0x4D4862: TestTemperatureController_WhenEnabled_ShouldAct_Test::TestBody() (in /home/lukasz/workspace/build-arduino-thermostat-Desktop-Domyślna/unit_tests)
==10176==    by 0x52DF4D: void testing::internal::HandleSehExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::Test, void>(testing::Test*, void (testing::Test::*)(), char const*) (in /home/lukasz/workspace/build-arduino-thermostat-Desktop-Domyślna/unit_tests)
==10176==    by 0x5281B6: void testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::Test, void>(testing::Test*, void (testing::Test::*)(), char const*) (in /home/lukasz/workspace/build-arduino-thermostat-Desktop-Domyślna/unit_tests)
==10176==    by 0x50C9A9: testing::Test::Run() (in /home/lukasz/workspace/build-arduino-thermostat-Desktop-Domyślna/unit_tests)
==10176== 
==10176== LEAK SUMMARY:
==10176==    definitely lost: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==10176==    indirectly lost: 387 bytes in 7 blocks
==10176==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10176==    still reachable: 74,460 bytes in 29 blocks
==10176==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10176== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==10176== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==10176== 
==10176== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==10176== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I'm not really good at googlemock implementation, but for me i seems like there are some expectations allocated, which are not released later. Or is it a false positive?

The question is: How do I deal with that? I want to inject mocks with unique_ptr's. I don't want to change the tested object's interface, of course.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11548191/1413395) helps a bit to solve your problem.